# Ember CLI Data Chaining data Models

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

I have a model made by 3 other nested models in Ember and I want to use data from one of them for a parameter for another one.

I have got a model to set the configuration of my App (hotTopicConfig) The thing is that I want to use data from hotTopicConfig to use it as a parameter in hotTopics Model

```
return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
    hotTopicConfig: self.store.findQuery('hot-topic-config', {
        touchpointId: params.touchpointId,
    }).then(function (results) {
        self.set('periodType', results.get('periodType'))
        return results.get('firstObject');
    }),

    hotTopicSortByType: self.store.find('hot-topic-sort-by-type'),

    hotTopics: self.store.findQuery('hot-topic', {
        touchpointId: params.touchpointId,
        periodType: HERE I WANT TO USE DATA FROM hotTopicConfig
    }).then(function (results) {
        return results.get('firstObject');
    })
```

I have used several solutions but none of them workt for me, like external and additional calls to AJAX call.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

how about doing like this

```
var config = self.store.findQuery('hot-topic-config', {
    touchpointId: params.touchpointId,
});

return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
    hotTopicConfig: config.then(function (results) {
        return results.get('firstObject');
    }),

    hotTopicSortByType: self.store.find('hot-topic-sort-by-type'),

    hotTopics: config.then(function (results) {
        var periodType = results.get('periodType');
        return self.store.findQuery('hot-topic', {
            touchpointId: params.touchpointId,
            periodType: periodType
        }).then(function (results) {
            return results.get('firstObject');
        })
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have provided has been to to an AJAX request on beforeModel and set :

```
beforeModel : function(){
        var self = this;
        var touchpointId = window.location.href.split('hot-topics/');

        return Ember.$.get('someUrl')
            .done(function(data){
                self.controllerFor('hot-topics').set('defaultPeriod', data.hotTopicConfig[0].defaultPeriod);
            });
    },


hotTopics : self.store.findQuery('hot-topic', { 
                        touchpointId : params.touchpointId,
                        periodType : self.controllerFor('hot-topics').get('defaultPeriod')
            }).then(function(results){
                return results.get('firstObject');
            })
```